# Problem with usb printer ports in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, printing

I have 2 USB printers installed; they are assigned their ports `/dev/usb/lp0` and `/dev/usb/lp1`.

But when I reboot my PC it often changes between them, for example, Printer 1 is assigned the port `/dev/usb/lp0` before reboot and after I reboot it changes to the port `/dev/usb/lp1`.

Since each one has different paper settings this is a problem. How can I stop it from happening?

Comment: I don't know enough about the details to write a fully fleshed-out answer, but the keyword you might want to look into is "udev rules".

Answer (score 0):

You may use `udev`rules, as @Henning said.

First find out some unique information for the printers by executing

```
$ sudo udevadm info -a /dev/usb/lp0
calling: info
.
.
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
.
.
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="1763"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9"
    ATTRS{serial}=="8025E2"
```

(and equivalent for `lp1`)

This is just an example, but usually `Vendor`, `Product`and `serial`are sufficient. Now you can create a simple `udev-rule` to let udev create a unique name (link) for this printer when it is added. Create a file in `/etc/udev/rules.d` e.g. with `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/99-myprinters.rules` to hold two lines like:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="lp[0-9]*", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1763", ATTRS{serial}=="8025E2", SYMLINK+="printer1"
```

Of course you have to replace the ids and serial by what `udevadm`reported. This means:

When a device is added (`ACTION=ADD`) that is an usb printer (`SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", KERNEL=="lp[0-9]*"`) which matches vendor, product and serial number, add a symbolic link in `/dev` with the name `printer1` (well, you may name the printer as you want, maybe something more intuitive).

Important: The name of the rules file has to end in `.rules`, otherwise it will be ignored. And you should respect the naming conventions for udev rules.

Sometimes printer drivers installation creates their own udev rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d`; just look at them for examples.

You can test this with `sudo udevadm test <devicepath>`, where `<devicepath>`has to be the full path reported by `udevadm info`, e.g. `/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.2/usb2/2-3/2-3.2/2-3.2:1.1/usbmisc/lp0`.